# Escaping Characters in Spark.SQL() with Wildcard Inside of Query

Tags: pyspark, impala

Sample Query:

```
df = spark.sql("""
select distinct key,
      coalesce(get_json_object(col2,'$.value'), case when col2 like '%value\\u0022: false%' then 'false' when col2 like '%value\\u0022: true%' then 'true' end) as col2flag
from Table
""")
```

In Impala there exists a payload structure with \u0022 for the value needed. Escaping this unicode character in Impala SQL is done with an extra \ slash.

When this DF is pulled via Pyspark the values that are pulled from the case statement is null when it is expected to be true. I have tried the above query with one forward slash and two.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17647

Answer (score 0):

Try set `spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals` to `'true'` then use four slashes  to parse literal `\` in the strings. See this example here :

```
spark.sql("select * from df1").show(truncate=False)

+---+---------------------+
|id |str                  |
+---+---------------------+
|1  |value\x2 : true      |
|2  |test value\u2 : false|
|3  |val: true            |
+---+---------------------+

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parser.escapedStringLiterals", "true")

spark.sql(" select * from df1 where str like '%value\\\\u%'  ").show(truncate=False)

+---+---------------------+
|id |str                  |
+---+---------------------+
|2  |test value\u2 : false|
+---+---------------------+
```